# Enable Proguard on Android Library Project

Tags: android, proguard

I have a standalone Android Library Project and I would like to compile this project with Proguard enabled. I'm using Android Studio 1.0 and I have enabled Proguard with             minifyEnabled true. However after a clean build I get the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':test_sdk:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Try invalidatecache/Restart

Comment: Is there any limitation on enabling proguard on library projects ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added the following proguard rules

```
-keep public class * {
    public *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    public *;
}

-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses
```

It seems to work now